# Java Prgoram : Reading Excel File 2003

Tags: java

I am getting following error message :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet index (0) is out of range (0..-1)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.validateSheetIndex(HSSFWorkbook.java:429)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getSheetAt(HSSFWorkbook.java:825)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getSheetAt(HSSFWorkbook.java:73)
    at gov.adam.main.ExcelFileReader.readExcelFile(ExcelFileReader.java:106)
    at gov.adam.main.AllFileFolderReader.fileList(AllFileFolderReader.java:73)
    at gov.adam.main.AllFileFolderReader.fileList(AllFileFolderReader.java:62)
    at gov.adam.main.AllFileFolderReader.fileList(AllFileFolderReader.java:62)
    at gov.adam.main.AllFileFolderReader.main(AllFileFolderReader.java:151)
W:\Walg
```

I could not figure it out why it is out of range. I have only one sheet. Please help.

Here is my following code :

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.PushbackInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

/**
*
* @author 
*/

public class ExcelFileReader {

public static BufferedWriter readExcelFile(File excelFile,   BufferedWriter       reportWiter, int noOFLine,String fileName) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Reading Excel file first " + noOFLine + " lines");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(excelFile);

    try {

       Workbook workbook = null;
        if(fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xlsx")){
            //workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

    workbook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.createNewPushbackInputStream  (inputStream));

        }else if(fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xls")){
           // workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

   workbook = (HSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(new PushbackInputStream(inputStream));
        }


        //Get the number of sheets in the xlsx file
        int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();

        System.out.println("Number of Sheet " + numberOfSheets + " lines");

        //loop through each of the sheets
        for (int a = 0; a <= numberOfSheets; a++) {


            System.out.println("a : " + a + " lines");

            //Get the nth sheet from the workbook

            if(fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xlsx")){
                //workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

                a=a+1;
                XSSFSheet  sheet = (XSSFSheet) workbook.getSheetAt(a);
                Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();

                int i = 0;

                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Row nextRow = iterator.next();
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
                    String line = "";
                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                line += cell.getStringCellValue();
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                line += cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                line += cell.getNumericCellValue();
                                break;
                        }

                    }
                    System.out.println(line);
                    reportWiter.write(line + "\n");

                    if (i == (noOFLine - 1)) {
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }

            }

            else if(fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xls")){
               // workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

                HSSFSheet  sheet = (HSSFSheet) workbook.getSheetAt(a);





            Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();

            int i = 0;

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Row nextRow = iterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
                String line = "";
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            line += cell.getStringCellValue();
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                            line += cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            line += cell.getNumericCellValue();
                            break;
                    }

                }
                System.out.println(line);
                reportWiter.write(line + "\n");

                if (i == (noOFLine - 1)) {
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }

        }

    } }catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
    reportWiter.flush();
    return reportWiter;
}

}
```

Comment: "for (int a = 0; a <= numberOfSheets; a++) {" is wrong.  It ought to read "for (int a = 0; a < numberOfSheets; a++) {".  If you use <= you will exceed the value of max index by one when you satisfy the = part of <=.

Comment: I tried with ( int a=0; a<numberOfSheets;a++) . But I am getting a=0 and numberOfSheets=0). It skipped reading excel file. However, I have one excel sheet in my file. I don't know why numberOfSheets is getting 0.

Comment: Be sure you are applying .getNumberOfSheets() to a valid HSSFWorkbook object, *not* an HSSFSheet object.  Also make sure that the FileInputStream you use to create the HSSFWorkbook object is actually reading a valid .xlsx file.  If you are reading an .xls file created by too early a ver. of Excel, that will mess you up.  Also make sure the .xls{x} file you are using is in fact a real Excel file created by Excel, and not just a CSV or TSV file with an .xls{x} extension, or it must have been created by the POI API.